# Trouble Storing URL in NSURL Variable

Tags: objective-c, json, nsurl

At the end of this method, "address" (NSURL variable) returns nil, even though "countyName" returns @"Alameda".  What am I doing wrong?

```
-(void) getDataUrl {

if ([countyName isEqual: @"Alameda"]) {
    NSURL * fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.myservername.com/alameda.php"];
    self.address = fileURL;
   }

if ([countyName isEqual: @"Napa"]) {
    NSURL * fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.myservername.com/napa.php"];
    self.address = fileURL;
   }

if ([countyName isEqual: @"San Luis Obispo"]) {
    NSURL * fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.myservername.com/sanluisobispo.php"];
    self.address = fileURL;
   }
```

}

Comment: Could you give us more details as in where are you using this method? Are you expecting this method to return you some value?

Comment: When you say "address", I assume you mean self.address.  Is self.address being overwritten to nil anywhere else in the code? More context would be helpful.

Comment: I previously was retrieving data using #define getDataUrl @"http://www.myservername.com/cities.php", but that retrieved every city in my database.  I need to be able to retrieve city records based on the county that was selected.  I'm passing the countyName via segue from a UITableView that contains an array of counties.  I expect this method to store the URL in the "address" variable where I can use it in my retrieveData method, where I retrieve and parse JSON.

Comment: "address" is a NSURL variable declared in the header file. I don't believe it's being overwritten anywhere.  It's simply being used to pass a URL to another method.  Sorry if that didn't answer your question.  I'm an Objective C noob.

Comment: Can we see the code how address is declared and how it is passed to the other method? You should be checking for self.address, not just address in the retrieveData method.

Comment: Unrelated, but a couple of better coding strategies...  If you have a lot of cities, you generally don't want an if statement for every city (especially if server name all the same).  Put the page name of the url in a dictionary and just retrieve that based on countryname.  Also, if self.address is just being passed to another method, getDataUrl should just return the url directly.  No need to store that in a class member variable if it is only being used for passing data along from one method to the next.

Comment: rimsky - that makes total sense because my server name is all the same, but I'm not sure how I'd go about that.   Address is declared @property (strong, nonatomic) NSURL *address;  I can't show you how address is used in the other method as the other method previously looked for an NSString, but I changed it to an NSURL and I haven't yet dealt with that.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here was to create a plist containing an array of dictionaries.  Each dictionary held the name of a county and a url for the php script for that county.  The plist was used to populate a tableview, and then the selected row was pushed to another tableview using the variable "countyName".  "countyName" held the county name and the url.  I then used countyName in my retrieveData method like this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[countyName valueForKey:@"weburl"]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];

    jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
```

Thanks to everyone for taking the time to respond.